# Perl WWW::Mechanize returns the page instead of response

Tags: perl

I am trying to automate user search process from our University because I need to use it frequently. I found that `WWW::Mechanize` from perl is a good way to do it. However, when I try the following code, the response is always the original web page and not the query result that I am expecting:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

$mech->get('http://find.pitt.edu');
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields    => { query  => 'Barroso', },
    button    => 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearchAll'
);

$mech->success or die "post failed: ", $mech->response->status_line;
print $mech->content_type();
print $mech->response()->content();
```

I am pretty new to Perl, so I am doing something obviously wrong but was not able to figure out after reading the `WWW::Mechanize` documentation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize) doesn't support JavaScript. Try [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) or similar.

Comment: @choroba Thanks. I am on a cluster login node that doesn't have Firefox installed. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Just read the links I gave you, especially [this part](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#JavaScript).

Comment: @choroba Thanks. The suggested alternative all seem to need a service running on the host which is not possible on my setup. I asked this question on the reddit perl community and received an answer that is suitable to my needs. [Link to answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/6s63ny/perl_wwwmechanize_returns_the_page_instead_of/dlaki2u/).